# COUNTIF BIGQUERY

Tags: google-bigquery, countif

In BigQuery, I want to know for each player against which player he won the most and the least points

```
points_name_one  |points_name_two |name_one |name_two |concat_name  |   
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1                |  1             |Lou      |Max      |Lou - Max    |    
1                |  1             |Max      |Elie     |Max - Elie   |     
3                |  0             |Elie     |Zoe      |Elie - Zoe   |      
1                |  1             |Max      |Elie     |Max - Elie   |     
1                |  1             |Lou      |Max      |Lou - Max    |    
0                |  3             |Lou      |Max      |Lou - Max    |    
1                |  1             |Julien   |Max      |Julien - Max |         
1                |  1             |Max      |Elie     |Max - Elie   |     
3                |  0             |Elie     |Zoe      |Elie - Zoe   |      
0                |  3             |Zoe      |Lou      |Zoe - Lou    | 
3                |  0             |Lou      |Max      |Lou - Max    |    
1                |  1             |Max      |Elie     |Max - Elie   |
```

I think i have to used COUNTIF with over ( https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#countif ) but i try but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirements corretly, below query will show you opponent players from whom you got most and least points.

```sql
WITH games AS (
  SELECT name_one AS player, name_two AS opponent, points_name_one AS point  FROM sample
   UNION ALL
  SELECT name_two, name_one, points_name_two FROM sample
)
SELECT player, opponent, SUM(point) AS points,
       FIRST_VALUE(opponent) OVER w AS least_from, 
       LAST_VALUE(opponent) OVER w AS most_from, 
  FROM games
 GROUP BY 1, 2
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY player ORDER BY SUM(point) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)  
;
```

Output:

for example, **Elie** got 4 points from **Max** which is least and got 6 points from **Zoe** which is most.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider also below approach

```
select name_one as player, 
  array_agg(struct(name_two as most_from, points as most_points) order by points desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*,
  array_agg(struct(name_two as least_from, points as least_points) order by points limit 1)[offset(0)].* 
from (
  select name_one, name_two, sum(points_name_one) points
  from your_table group by 1,2 
  union all
  select name_two, name_one, sum(points_name_two) 
  from your_table group by 1,2
)
group by player
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]